# Insert using db_link gets invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00904

I'm building a query that locates specific records across multiple databases and inserts them in the master DB that has access to all the rest.

But even if the select works well, the insert fails giving me an invalid identifier using a synonym that doesn't even exist.

**Query:**

```
            INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE 

            Select Distinct tr.hmy, trim(tr.uref), tr.stotalamount, tr.upostdate, tr.sdateoccurred
            ,trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) 
            ,trim(v.ucode) 
            ,trim(v.ulastname) 
            ,trim(p.scode) 
            ,trim(p.saddr1) 
            ,trim(b.scode) 
            ,trim(b.sdesc) 
            ,l.icloseday 
            , case when l.icloseday <> 31 then trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) + (l.icloseday - 1 ) else last_day(trunc(tr.sdateoccurred )) end
            , case when l.icloseday <> 31 then 
            case when trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) + l.icloseday <= trunc(tr.sdateoccurred) then add_months((tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1),1)
              else trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) end
              else trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) end 
            ,trim(u.uname)
            ,'' 
            from trans@db_link tr
            join detail@db_link d on d.hchkorchg = tr.hmy
            join vendor@db_link v on tr.haccrualacct = v.hmyperson
            join property@db_link p on p.hmy = d.hprop
                 and p.itype = 3
            join bank@db_link b on b.hmy = tr.hperson
            join pmuser@db_link u on u.hmy = tr.husercreatedby
            join lockout@db_link l on l.hprop = p.hmy
            where 
            1=1 
            and tr.itype = 2 
            and tr.manualcheck <> 0 
            and tr.sdatecreated between to_date(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')) and to_date(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'), 12)-1)
            and case when l.icloseday <> 31 then 
              case when trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) + l.icloseday <= trunc(tr.sdateoccurred) then add_months((tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1),1)
                else trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) end
                else trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) end <> trunc(tr.UPOSTDATE)
```

**Error:**

```
            ORA-00904: "A2"."HUSERCREATEDBY": invalid identifier
            ORA-02063: preceding line from db_link
```

The weirdest part: all these database have the same schema but only some of them fail with this error when i loop through all.

**Update 11/14/2017:**

Looking more into it, it seems that if i eliminate any one of the two following conditions the INSERT has no issue, but i keep looking at them and don't know why the engine would error out because of these two when just the simple SELECT has no issue.

```
and tr.sdatecreated between to_date(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')) and to_date(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'), 12)-1)
```

**or**

```
and case when l.icloseday <> 31 then 
                             case when trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) + l.icloseday <= trunc(tr.sdateoccurred) then add_months((tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1),1)
                             else trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) end
                           else trunc(tr.sdateoccurred ) - (to_number(to_char(tr.sdateoccurred ,'DD')) - 1) end <> trunc(tr.UPOSTDATE)
```

Comment: Looks like grants are missing, You need to grant select access to other user.

Comment: But if i run the Select without the Insert there is no problem. The error comes in only if i want to insert the 'select' data.

Comment: Yes..So `INSERT` grant is missing.

Comment: Is there an INSERT grant specific to data that comes from a db_link? because a regular insert into that table without using cross DB data has no issue running. 

the INSERT fails only when i use the SELECT from another database.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why this issue occurred, but if anyone runs into this as well, i worked around it by having the db_link insert the remote information into a remote table and then i insert that information into a local table in my master database.

```
begin
    sql_update:='DROP TABLE AUDIT_TABLE';
    execute immediate 'begin dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@'||v_database_name||'(:sql_update);  end;' using sql_update;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          IF SQLCODE = -942 THEN
            NULL; -- suppresses ORA-00942 exception
          ELSE
             RAISE;
          END IF;
END;

sql_update := 'create table AUDIT_TABLE (table structure)';
execute immediate 'begin dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@'||v_database_name||'(:sql_update);  end;' using sql_update;
commit;

sql_update := q'[
              INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE@#DB_NAME# 
              Select {query here}
                ]';
execute immediate replace('begin ' || sql_update || ';  end;','#DB_NAME#', v_database_name);
commit;

sql_update := q'[
              INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE select * from AUDIT_TABLE@#DB_NAME#
                ]';
execute immediate replace('begin ' || sql_update || ';  end;','#DB_NAME#', v_database_name);
commit;
```